# Why am I unable to call a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some Javascript that is supposed to call two functions but it's failing to do so. I suspect I may know why but I don't know how to fix it. Here's my jQuery:

```
var is_mobile = false,
    page = document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ul = $('nav > ul'),
        li = ul.children('li'),
        href = li.find('a[href*="'+page+'"]'),
        is404 = true;
    if($('#mobile').css('display')=='none') {
        is_mobile = true;       
    }
    if(is_mobile) {
        orderList();
        prepareList();
    }
});
/************************/
/* Reorders the list   */
/**********************/
function orderList() {
    $(li.find('a[href*="contact.php"]')).removeAttr('style');
        //move element to top
        ul.prepend(href.parent());
        if(page != ""){
            li.children('a').each(function(){
                if (page == $(this).attr('href')) {
                    is404 = false;
                }
            });
            if (is404) {
                //if the user is on a page not in the nav, add a 404 link at the top of the nav
                ul.prepend("<li><a href='404NotFound.php'><icon><img src='images/404-icon.png'></icon>404</a></li>");
            }
        }
};
/**************************************************************/
/* Prepares the list to be dynamically expandable/collapsible   */
/**************************************************************/
function prepareList() {
    $ul.find('li:has(ul)').unbind('click').click(function(event) {
        if(this == event.target) {
            $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
            $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
        }
        return false;
    }).addClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded').children('ul').hide();

    //Hack to add links inside the cv
    $('#expList a').unbind('click').click(function() {
        window.open($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });
    //Create the button functionality
    $('#expandList').unbind('click').click(function() {
        $('.collapsed').addClass('expanded');
        $('.collapsed').children().show('medium');
    })
    $('#collapseList').unbind('click').click(function() {
        $('.collapsed').removeClass('expanded');
        $('.collapsed').children().hide('medium');
    })
};
```

I suspect that the Javascript may be failing to call the functions because they have jQuery in them, but if that's the case I'm absolutely clueless as to how to fix it. By the way, `is_mobile` is returning true when I check this on my iTouch. Any ideas guys. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the functions aren't being called? Or are they being called but don't produce results? Try putting a breakpoint in each function, or a call to console.log(), or even an alert(), so you  can see if they're being called. Looks to me like they should be called.

However, I think you have problems with variable scope. You define variables `ul` and `li` inside your document.ready() function, but reference them in `orderList()` and `prepareList()`, which are defined at the top level. So your variables aren't visible to your functions. And, in `prepareList()`, you reference `$ul`, rather than `ul`. `$ul` isn't defined at all, so it's reated as a(n empty) global when first referenced.

Try defining these variable outside all the functions along with `is_mobile` and then don't redefine them with `var` in the `document.ready()` function, just assign values to them there. Or, if you don't like globals, wrap all this up into a module -- but you'll still need to either make the variables visible to all functions in the module, or pass them in to the functions as parameters.

Comment: They have to be set in the `document.ready()` function because they're being set based on elements in the HTML.

Comment: Yes, they have to be set -- initialized -- in the `ready()` function. But they don't have to be declared there, where they're hidden from the other scripts. (I see I wrote 'defined'; 'declared' is more accurate.) If they're declared outside `ready()`, they're visible both to the `ready()` script to set their values, and to the other functions to read those values. Or, the functions can be moved inside `ready()` so they're in the same scope, as suggested in the accepted answer.